# How to write word count code using map in Perl?

Tags: perl

My sample data:

```
1 2 A
1 2 3 B
1 A
1 2 3 C
1 3 A
1 3 B
```

I want to count the number of last word

my Perl code:

```
my %tmp;
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    my $last=(split)[-1];
    $tmp{$last}++;
}
while(my ($k,$v)=each %tmp){
    print "$k=>$v\n"
}
```

It works fine. I recently learned `grep`,`map`,`sort` , but do not understand well. I tried to write above code using several `map` in one line. Not succeed.

Could you please show me how?

Thanks.

Comment: The only part `map` would be suited for here would be to make a list of the last "words" in your string. `grep` has no use at all, and `sort` might be used to sort the count frequency in the last step.

Answer (score 2):

`map` transforms a list. You have no list to transform.

`grep` filters a list. You have no need to filter anything.

`sort` sorts. You could use it to sort the output. (If you problems sorting the output, feel free to ask a question about it. Be sure to including a description of your problem along with a demonstration of it.)

Answer (score 2):

Is this the sort of thing you mean?

It may be fun to play with, but you should *always* go for clarity over fancy coding. `map` and `grep` are rarely significantly faster than the equivalent `for` loop, and can use up much more memory.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %tmp;
$tmp{$_}++ for map { (split)[-1] } <>;
print for map "$_ => $tmp{$_}\n", sort keys %tmp;
```

**output**

```
A => 3
B => 2
C => 1
```

Comment: `$tmp{$_}++ for map { (split)[-1] } <>;` is a bad way of writing `$tmp{ (split)[-1] }++ while <>;` you might as well have used `map { ++$tmp{ (split)[-1] } } <>;`.

Comment: @ikegami: I disagree with your first statement and don't understand the second: there is no point in misusing `map` when there is no list mapping going on.